# a simple program in python , I am stumped

Tags: python, range, augmented-assignment

```
m = 0
for i in range(1,1000):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        m += m
print m
```

This gives `0` as answer.
Answer should be `233168`.

Could the line ending in my IDE be an issue?
I am using pycharm.

EDIT: note to self - take a break. I found the typo as soon as I posted this. I was having some problem with ide and line ending just before this. anyway thanks :) Troll away

Comment: Err, you're adding `m` to `m` which always is `0`. What else do you expect?

Comment: yep, i realized that after i posted it. i have lost it :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the line:

```
m += m
```

You're adding `m` to `m` itself; i.e. you're always adding `0` to `0`.

You probably meant:

```
m += i
```

Comment: holy crap >.< i need to sleep before starting on project euler problems. thanks